# Auto login in iOS app doesn't work 100% of the time in AppDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, appdelegate

I have code in my appdelegate that checks to see if a user's credentials are stored in a singleton object's dictionary property (that were loaded from the keychain) and if so, it logs them in automatically. About 1 in 50 times after you close the app and open it back up later, it does not log you in automatically and just takes you to our login/signup viewcontroller. I do know that if you re-close the app and re-open it, it logs you in fine.

There are two things I can think that would cause this problem:

1. The only way I can reproduce this is if I turn off my network connection. So given this, is there any reason why a login api call from appdelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions would not work 2% of the time?
2. If for some reason in the app delegate I cannot access the keychain 2% of the time.
3. If there is some issue with my singleton code where the dictionary object that is loaded from the keychain on init isn't available.

As a backup, I added a timer on the login/splash page that re-pings our server to see if they are logged in, but this just seems unnecessary.

This is my singleton object:

```
@interface ABCLoginState ()
@property (strong) NSDictionary *dict;
@end

@implementation ABCLoginState

- (id)init
{
    if (nil != (self = [super init])) {
        self.dict = ABCGetLoginInformation();
    }
    return self;
}

+ (ABCLoginState *)shared
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    static ABCLoginState *loginState;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        loginState = [[ABCLoginState alloc] init];
    });
    return loginState;
}

- (BOOL)hasLoginData
{
    return self.dict != nil;
}
```

This is how I get my login credentials saved on the phone:

```
NSDictionary *ABCGetLoginInformation()
{
NSDictionary *d;
d = @{ (__bridge id)kSecClass: (__bridge id)kSecClassGenericPassword,
       (__bridge id)kSecAttrService: SECSERVICENAME,
       (__bridge id)kSecReturnAttributes: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue,
       (__bridge id)kSecReturnData: (__bridge id)kCFBooleanTrue };
CFDictionaryRef found = nil;
SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)d, (CFTypeRef *)&found);

if (!found) {
    /*
     *  No credentials.
     */

    return nil;
} else {
    /*
     *  We found a username and password. Return them
     */

    NSDictionary *data = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)found;
    NSString *username = (NSString *)[data objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
    NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[data objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUserDefaults *ud = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSInteger userID = [ud integerForKey:@"UserID"];

    return @{ @"username": username, @"password": password, @"userid": @( userID ) };
}
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Another potential issue could be when the app is in the background and is moved to the suspended state to the not running state. When it reaches this state it somehow resets the app?

Comment: What happens if you delay the access to the keychain a bit (2 seconds or so) i. e. by dispatching the code via the run loop?

Comment: Haven't tried that but will attempt. This is a tricky one to debug as it doesn't seem to give me issues unless the app is in the background for many hours (e.g. this generally happens when I re-open the app in the morning).

Comment: @Hawk have you tried checking the `protectedDataAvailable`:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/protectedDataAvailable bool?  The keychain maybe locked to your app for periods of time if your phone has a pin.  My guess is that delay has to do with iCloud syncing the keychain? Also, check out `UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable`:https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/#//apple_ref/c/data/UIApplicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable

Comment: @mattyice That is exactly, what I think: It is protected a short while.

Comment: I think you may be on to something. Will tinker around to see if the keychain stays locked. Thanks so much!